# How will i make uiWebView to handle two requests fired back to back

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

I have a scenario where i render a HTML page in the webview. On click of a button in that webview two requests are fired. (Single click two request triggered)
First requqest (onClick) -> to open a new window and render a different page in that new window (i intercept the new window pattern and render that page in a overlay). This is a child thread.
Second request (Action) -> to refresh the current page. This is the parent thread.

Now the issue is by the time the first request reaches startonLoad method of the webview the second requests intercepts the flow and it kills the first request and continues with its flow. As a result only the second request is processed and the first request is dropped.
First request ends with a error saying (Connection dropped; Error code -999)

There are scenarios where only the first request is fired. Application works beautifully that time. Issue exists only for the two requests back to back scenario.

Requirement: I want to successfully process both the request (or) Is there a way i can intercept the second request and make it wait until the first request is served.

Appreciate any suggestions. Sorry for hte lenghty thread. Let me know if you need more clariffications.

Comment: If you return `NO` from `- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType;`, do both requests reach your delegate?

Comment: Thanks for the response Ian. Yes i did try it but in this case the second request doesnt reach delegate.

Comment: If you're not getting the second request when you specifically deny the first request, it seems to me that you'll have to change your server code.

Comment: Sorry for responding late Ian. What i tried to do is deny the second request (by intercepting that URL pattern and return NO) and allowed the first request to complete. In this case the first request is successfull. but since the second request is denied with return NO it is not served.

Comment: I also tried making the second request to wait for 5 seconds so that teh response from teh first request is served by that time. It works fine. Byut i cant rely on this.   ------------ What i wanted to achieve is hold the second request until the first request is served successfully. Is there a way to do this??